# How can I get VIM to stop indenting close tags?

Tags: html, vim

I use MacVim to edit HTML files. It already provides a reasonable built-in indention. However, whenever I have a new tag pair:

```
<div id='test'>
```

and want to close it, it always becomes

```
<div id='test'>
    </div>
```

rather than

```
<div id='test'>
</div>
```

which is kind of annoying. Any hints on how to fix this?

EDIT: Part of my `.vimrc` that might be relevant:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: Your markup may need fixing. Whenever I have this behaviour, there’s an error in my markup further up.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't get exactly what you mean. This is an example so I didn't put anything in the div. And I usually write a pair of tags before I put something in it, if this is what you mean by 'behaviour'.

Comment: Usually, the closing tag is pushed to the left when you hit enter. If that's not the case, could you post the relevant parts of your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: clwen, I believe what @KonradRudolph was referring to was you have invalid markup where the latter `</div>` was closing a previously unclosed `div`, and hence the spacing. The problem I have is I don't know what the markup would be that would cause that type of spacing you describe. I have seen Eclipse do that before, though, and it would annoy me.

Comment: @clwen, are you sure the closing tags stays there after you hit `<CR>`?

Comment: That's Vim's own notation of `Enter`.

Comment: @romainl Not after `<CR>`. However, under this context `<CR>` is not my usual workflow so it's still annoying. What I often do is `O` to edit what inside the pair of tags.

Comment: OK then, what you describe is simply the default behavior. You should try [an alternative indent script…](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=html&script_type=indent&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search) I'd also suggest [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) and [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup). I do a lot of HTML and both plgins are incredibly useful.